No me funciona la paleta del ColorSchemeSeed en Flutter
Hola a penas estoy comenzando con Flutter y estoy tratando de hacer que mi AppBar coja el color primario dado un color con la propiedad ColorSchemeSeed sin embargo ponga el color que ponga siempre me sale un color similar al índigo por defecto como se muestra en la imagen

El código que tengo hasta es el siguiente:
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorApp = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.red),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),

      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('AppBar'),
          backgroundColor: colorApp.primary,
        ),

        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hola mundo',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50,
              color: colorApp.primary,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Si alguien pudieses ayudarme se lo agradecería. Ya he hecho también FullRestat incluso desinstalar e instale la aplicación y nada

El problema es que estaba accediendo al Theme.of(context).colorScheme antes de que este estuviese definido en el árbol de widgets por el MaterialApp
Lo que hice fue crear una clase independiente y acceder al color fuera de la clase MyApp y usarlo directamente en el Theme del AppBar
Este es el código resultante
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
        
      ),

      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorApp = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar'),
        backgroundColor: colorApp.primary,
      ),
    
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hola mundo',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 50,
            color: colorApp.primary,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Aqui en la imagen ya muestra el AppBar con el color deseado

